# A sequence of subsets of $\Bbb Z$ not containing nontrivial subgroups

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, abelian-groups, infinite-groups, integers

Is there a sequence $(A_n)$ of subsets of $\Bbb Z$ such that always $\{a-b\mid a,b\in A_{n+1}\}$ is a proper subset of $A_n$ and no $A_n$ contains an infinite subgroup of $(\Bbb Z,+)$?

---

<sup>(Ed.: this is a self-answered question)</sup>

Comment: This is your third question about this sort of sequence. It might be easier and more helpful if you can add some background and context to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. No proof is requested. But to show the correctness of the answer: Embed $\Bbb Z$ in the circle group $\Bbb T$. Let the $A_n$ be a base of neighborhoods of $1$ in the subspace topology such that $A_{n+1}A_{n+1}^{-1}\subseteq A_n$ with $A_1$ small enough. Then no $A_n$ can contain a subgroup of the embedded $\Bbb Z$. Because every subgroup has to be dense.